# Convert HTML table to canvas using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to convert html table to pdf. I have tried using jspdf. it works well with plain table . But doesn't works when there are images in the table. Now I am trying to convert at least to canvas and there by to pdf. But it is also not working when there are images.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
button{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js" ></script>
<script>
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target">
      <table>
      <tr><td> <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com"> </td>
      <td>saf</td></tr>
      <tr><td>saff</td>
      <td>wdqwewe</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/ahkrwt30/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue was quite simple please add

```
allowTaint:true,
```

as options like this

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    },
    allowTaint:true,
    useCORS: true,
    width:320,
    height:220
});
}
```

and it will solve your problem

ps: allowTaint: Whether to allow cross-origin images to taint the canvas

[update]
as @ℊααnd the better answer would be using
You need to set **useCORS** property to **true** in the options. This will load the image as CORS served.

check documentation https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html

Comment: @ℊααnd i tried this code locally and it worked i dont know why exactly it is not working on the jsfiddle anyhow i am gonna vote you up and update my answer

Answer (score 3):

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

You need to set `useCORS` property to `true` in the options. This will load the image as CORS served.

see [available options](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#available-options)

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

Since, the current host site *(w3schools.com)* of the image doesn't support CORS hence, you'd have to host the image on your local server or a site that supports cross-origin resource sharing        *(ie. imgur.com)*

*Here is a working example ...*

```js
var takeScreenShot = function() {
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
      useCORS: true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
         document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      },
      width: 320,
      height: 220
   });
}
```

```css
button {
   display: block;
   height: 20 px;
   margin - top: 10 px;
   margin - bottom: 10 px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WamrIt4.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com"> </td>
            <td>saf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>saff</td>
            <td>wdqwewe</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

Comment: @techhunter How did the other answer work for you? That shouldn't work. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. both are working. But i am accepting above it is simple for me. So i am up voting your answer.